# Why is $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ defined as $-\int_b^a f(x)dx$ for $b<a$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I know with this definition "mathematics doesn't break" (sorry I don't know how to express it better, I mean that calculations and proofs work out), but is there a way you can interprete it? I figured that visually it would mean that $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ is equal to the area above the graph of f mirrored about the x-axis in the intervall $(b,a)$, which is not very insightful to me. How can you make sense of it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a point, i don't think $b \lt a$ must be true for this definition.

Comment: It agrees with the more general notion of integrating along an oriented space, with $[b, a]$ having the opposite orientation of $[a, b]$. What exactly do you mean by "interpret"? There's nothing particularly interesting or profound going on.

Comment: this is just a convention that makes easier some algebra with integrals

Comment: I like the "mathematics doesn't break" idea. You can go very far by doing lots of fairly approachable examples, in each case checking for errors in your own work, and very gradually building up intuition for the particular topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, the “area metaphor” for the integral doesn't justify this convention that well.  Negative area is kind of dubious.

You might try instead the “displacement metaphor” for the integral.  If $v(t)$ is the velocity of a particle at time $t$, then $\int_{a}^b v(t)\,dt$ is the displacement between the particle at time $a$ and time $b$.  I say *displacement* instead of *distance* to allow for direction.  If positive displacement were measured to the right, then negative displacement would go to the left.

What would $\int_b^a v(t)\,dt$ be?  One way to think about it is the same displacement result, but instead running time *backwards* from $b$ to $a$.  And the displacement from $t=b$ to $t=a$ (backwards) should be the *opposite* of the displacement from $t=a$ to $t=b$.  Meaning, same magnitude but opposite sign.

Answer (score 2):

$\int_a^bf(x)dx=-\int_b^af(x)dx$ in general...  just look at the definition of the integral as a limit of Riemann sums (we get the exact same sums except moving in the reverse direction from $b$ to $a$)

Consider, for instance,  an increasing $f$ and a partition of $[a,b]$ into one interval...
You get a lower sum $f(a)(b-a)$ which corresponds to a lower sum $f(a)(a-b)$ for the second integral.  In this way you can pair off the terms of the approximating sums...

As we are dealing for the most part with "nice" functions,  i.e. integrable, we can break the function into increasing and decreasing parts, and then add up and take limits...

Alternatively,  and this is sort of "hand waving", we can replace $dx$ by $-dx$ in moving from $b$ to $a$...

Answer (score 1):

You can (often) think of that area for $a < b$ and positive $f$ as what's on your left as you move from $a$ to $b$, up to $f$, back along the graph then down to $a$.

In that model areas on your right are negative. That gives the correct answer when $f$ takes on negative values, and it reverses sign when you reverse direction by swapping $a$ and $b$.

Comment: That’s a great answer. But at the OP’s stage it would be useful to add another explanation: we define it like this for convenience. This is just a o we can blindly apply (and prove!) FTC without worrying to check $a<b$ (and consider the other case separately) every single time.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(t)$ is your velocity at time $t,$ then $\int_{t_0}^{t} f(t)\,dt$ is the amount of distance you must add to your position at time $t_0$ to get your position at time $t$. This wouldn't be true for $t<t_0$ if we didn't define it this way. In particular, we'd want $\int_{t_0}^{t_1} f(t)\,dt=-\int_{t_1}^{t_0} f(t)\,dt$ if we wanted this to work property.

Answer (score 1):

We can state that if a < b, then the length of the interval [a, b], $L = b - a$ and what the define integral make is suming all $\delta x$ from a to b, of course $L=\int_{a}^{b}dx=b-a$, the integral is the the interval length, if you compute it backwards $-L=-\int_{b}^{a}dx=a-b=-(b-a)$. Moreover in the Riemann sum partition's definition you have a < b and $P=\{a=x_0<x_1<...<x_n=b\}$ to define $\int_{a}^{b}dx$ so if you take the integral from b to a, what your are doing is suming up to the negative side since you start from b but you sum negative infinitesimals with respect to b.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the integral must satisfy *additivity w.r.t. integrals*, which implies
$$\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm d x+\int_b^a f(x)\,\mathrm d x=\int_a^a f(x)\,\mathrm d x=0.$$

Comment: Well, *must* is a strong word.  We would like the additivity property to be extensible to all the other cases besides $a < c < b$, so we make definitions compatible with it.

Comment: What would be the interest without additivity w.r.t. intervals? When would measure theory enter onto the scene?

Comment: Measure Theory doesn’t care about anti-intervals. Additivity is with respect to disjoint (and properly oriented) intervalas. Going from a to b and then back is neither disjoint nor properly oriented.